# With a locally hosted Traefik proxy, what should my "trustedIPs" be for Authelia

Tags: authentication, traefik

I had a working docker stack with my home media server using a single docker compose file:

```yml
version: "3"
secrets:
  authelia_jwt_secret:
    file: $SECRETS_PATH/authelia/jwt_secret
  authelia_session_secret:
    file: $SECRETS_PATH/authelia/session_secret
services:
  calibre-web:
    image: linuxserver/calibre-web:nightly
    container_name: calibre-web
    environment:
      - PUID=$PUID
      - PGID=$PGID
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.calibre-https.rule=Host(`books.pointerstop.ca`)
      - traefik.http.routers.calibre-https.middlewares=authelia@file
      - traefik.http.routers.calibre-https.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.calibre-https.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt
    volumes:
      - /srv/calibre/config/calibre-web:/config
      - /srv/calibre/CalibreLibrary:/Calibre_Library up
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - calibre
    expose:
      - 8083
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    command:
    - --api.insecure=true
    - --providers.docker
    - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
    - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
    - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=${LE_EMAIL}
    - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/config/acme.json
    - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.tlschallenge=true
    # - --certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    - --log.filePath=/var/log/traefik.log
    - --log.level=DEBUG
    - --providers.file.directory=/dynamic_config/
    - --providers.file.watch=true

    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.local`)
      ## Services - API
      - traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal
      ## Global redirect of EXTERNAL domains to HTTPS
      - traefik.http.routers.redirs.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.*pointerstop.ca}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.redirs.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.redirs.middlewares=redirect-to-https@file
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /var/log/media-server:/var/log
      - ${CONFIG_PATH}/traefik:/config
      - ./dynamic_config:/dynamic_config

  # Authelia (Lite) - Self-Hosted Single Sign-On and Two-Factor Authentication
  authelia:
    container_name: authelia
    image: authelia/authelia:latest
    # image: authelia/authelia:4.21.0
    restart: always
    expose:
      - 9091
    volumes:
      - $CONFIG_PATH/authelia:/config
    environment:
      - TZ=${TIME_ZONE}
      - AUTHELIA_JWT_SECRET_FILE=/run/secrets/authelia_jwt_secret
      - AUTHELIA_SESSION_SECRET_FILE=/run/secrets/authelia_session_secret
    secrets:
      - authelia_jwt_secret
      - authelia_session_secret
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      ## HTTP Routers
      - traefik.http.routers.authelia-rtr.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.authelia-rtr.rule=Host(`auth.pointerstop.ca`)
      - traefik.http.routers.authelia-rtr.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.authelia-rtr.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt
      ## Middlewares
      - traefik.http.routers.authelia-rtr.middlewares=chain-authelia@file
      ## HTTP Services
      - traefik.http.services.authelia-media-server.loadbalancer.server.port=9091
```

Now, I wanted to split out the proxy into a separate stack, so that I could add my business domains in a third stack, and have everything protected by Authelia.

So, I've created a docker network `proxy` and everything is using that network, with complete success except that after authenticating with Authelia https://books.pointerstop.ca/ (Calibre-web) wants to authenticate again.

I'm aware that I need to set `entrypoints.websecure.forwardedHeaders.trustedIPs` in Traefik, without which Traefik removes all the important headers, but I can't figure out what they should be. With everything in the same docker stack, I didn't need trustedIPs at all. Now that they're in different stacks, *but on the same network*, I don't understand what's changed. I tried setting `trustedIPs=172.0.0.0/8` which covers all the docker networks. `*.pointerstop.ca` are CNAMEs to `pointerstop.ddns.net`, and the only reported IP at https://books.pointerstop.ca/login is my external IP—but it seems wrong to require that (and it's dynamically assigned, so awkward to use) when it wasn't needed in the single stack setup.